# Merge branch B to Branch A

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I m running a jenkins pipeline for my project.
Jenkins pulls the repository from gitlab and then runs my pipeline.
So the problem is that i want to merge B to A on gitlab when the pipeline runs successfully.
This is my Jenkinsfile which of course doesn't satisfy my need because it gives me the error

> merge: test - not something we can merge

```
node {
try{
stage('Build'){
    def mavenHome  = tool 'Maven'
    checkout scm
    sh "mvn clean install"
}
stage('SonarQube') {
        steps {
            sh "mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.branch.name="+ env.BRANCH_NAME
        }
    }

stage('Merge with Dev') {

    sh "git checkout dev"
    sh "git pull gitlab dev"
    sh "git merge test"

    }



} catch(error){
    currentBuild.result = "FAILED"
    mail to: 'mail here',
    subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
    body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}"
}
}
```

I want to merge to be automatic, no merge request. Thank you

Comment: Try to do it from the command line on Jenkins machine, It looks like something is wrong with git not with Jenkins.

Comment: how to do that exactly ? i mean i m on my jenkins machine now but i have no physical git repository of my project on it. i m using gitlab which is also on the same machine tho.

Comment: The repository is cloned onto the machine. You need to find where it is cloning. You can use `sh 'pwd'`  in your script to find out an exact path where Jenkins has cloned your repository. 
On Linux usually Jenkins clone projects in `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace` directory

Comment: The path is `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/projettest_issue5-ZP3ZOFFJDVDMG2NKVVH5JTLVMAZGUC2OAY2C7E255STSKQUIUKVA` but this is not helping. i mean  it's not a git repository and i can't access the git repositry of gitlab.
What would be ideal if gitlab create a not bare repository on my server that i can access via jenkins and make my merges.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to create a merge request when the pipeline is successful and that's by using API.Well, it doesn't do exactly do what i want (directly merge the branch when possible) but it's good enough for now (automatically create a merge request in gitlab).
This is the final stage in jenkinsfile

```
    stage('Merge with Dev') {


     sh 'curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: APITOKENHERE" "GITURL/api/v4/projects/PROJECTID/merge_requests?source_branch='+env.BRANCH_NAME+'&target_branch=A&title='+env.BRANCH_NAME+'ToA"'


    }
```